# EEA family permit visa

Tags: uk

I'm having a permit which reads "residence card of a family member of a union citizen" issued to me by Italian authorities when my mum acquired Italian citizenship.I will like to know if i should apply for EEA family permit or i can travel with her to UK without the EEA family permit.Thank you.

Comment: Are you under 21 years old?  If not, are you dependent on your mother?

Answer (score 2):

You can travel to the UK without an EEA family permit.  See [Entering the UK as the holder of an Article 10 residence card](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card):

> If you are a non-EEA national who holds a valid genuine residence card, issued to you as the family member of an EEA national who is exercising free movement rights in another EEA State (i.e. not your EEA relative’s Member State of nationality) under Article 10 of Directive 2004/38/EC (the ‘Free Movement Directive’), you may use this document for travel to the UK if you are accompanying your EEA national relative here, or joining your EEA national relative in the UK.

There are four sections with details of the process.  In particular, you should note the required evidence, which includes your birth certificate, to prove your relationship with your mother.  If you are over 21, you should also provide evidence that you are still dependent on your mother.

There is anecdotal evidence on this site that the immigration officer is not likely to ask for this evidence, but you probably want to avoid a situation in which you *are* asked for it and don't have it.  I suppose that the older you are, the more likely you are to be asked.

Answer (score 2):

EEA regulation 2016 says a child can travel with him/her one of parent who is a European Union Citizen. 
In your case : 
1. You hold a Article 10/20 residence card
2. Your mother have Italian citizenship

If you are under 21 and dependent on your mother then you can travel to uk with her without a visa. 
I have seen cases like dependent son of age 30 was permitted to enter with Italian(achieved) Father.
Have a look :

[UK guidance on residence card 10/20](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card)